# How to change this iptables rule from eth1 to eth0?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

In [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn) OpenVPN howto have they this iptables rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun+ -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

which is made for a server with 2 NIC's.

I only have one NIC.

How would this iptables look like for a server with only 1 NIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above iptables rules use for this diagram:

```
client ----- (eth1) OpenVPN server (eth0) ----- LAN
  |                        |
  |________________(tun+)__|
```

so if you have only one NIC, something like this:

```
client ----- (eth0) OpenVPN server
   |                        |
   |________________(tun+)__|
```

you can write iptables rules like belows:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

Remove the 3 last FORWARD chain rules.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you linked, `eth1` is the **external interface**, while `eth0` is the **LAN interface**. Those iptables rules make possible for VPN connections **from the outside** to access the local LAN.

You don't need them if using a single `eth0`, a part, maybe, the lines:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

in case you have a default `DROP` policy in iptables (or if you use a software firewall inteface,
you need to allow connections to port 1194).

That said, what's the need for a VPN with just one ethernet interface? Or do you have a **WAN** and a **LAN** IP on the same interface?

Comment: I would have liked to have two NICs, but all IPs on the LAN are public, but in a DMZ. So I guess even if I had two NICs I would still  to have inbound and outbound on the same NIC... So all LAN IPs are also WAN IPs, which makes testing a VPN hard =)